# Excel nested IF, AND, OR with 3 outcomes

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I wanted to ask this in a general way since it's a homework question and I want to try to figure it out.  I'm having trouble determine where to put the IF,AND,OR and the outcomes.
Can you help me with the general syntax of this statement?

**IF A AND B THEN 1 IF C OR D THEN 2 OTHERWISE 3.**

If I break it in pieces I can get it but I can't figure out how to put it together.
Thank you.

Comment: Show how you would break it into pieces.

Comment: for the or:  IF(OR(C="X",D="Y"),"2","3")      and:  IF(AND(A="Z",B="W","1","3")  but i'm not sure how to put them together

Answer (score 2):

write out the formula just like you said in bold.

```
=IF(AND("Condition A","Condition B"), 1 , IF(OR("Condition C", "Condition D"),2,3))
```

Every IF statement consists of:

```
IF( Logical check, true result, False result)
```

In your case your first logical check is that BOTH A and B are true.  If they are both true then you want 1.  So your formula starts with:

```
IF(AND(A,B),True Result, False Result)
```

For your true result you want 1.  So your formula becomes:

```
IF(AND(A,B),1,False Result)
```

So if A and or B is false then you wind up in the False Result section.  When this occurs, you will want to check to see if C or D is true.  This is where nesting comes in and your formula looks like:

```
IF(AND(A,B),1,IF(OR(C,D),True Result, False Result))
```

So if either C or D is true you want a results of 2 so your formula becomes:

```
IF(AND(A,B),1,IF(OR(C,D),2, False Result))
```

This leave us with the final condition, where A and or B is False and both C and D are false.  Also your catch all part of your checks.  When all checks fail, you want 3.  The final formula becomes:

```
IF(AND(A,B),1,IF(OR(C,D),2, 3))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The explanation definitely helped and after several hours, I was able to finally come up with the correct responses.  I really appreciate the help.